# 18v nimh battery charger

Tags: charger

For the 18V +/- NIMH battery pack (2 x 9V packs in series @ 200mAh) that I use to run my phono preamp, I need a simple trickle charge circuit. The LM317 IC seems to be the one that is used a lot. 
Does any one have a proven circuit that would work with a very low charging current of say around 20-30 mA?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the LM317 circuit that you already found?  It's usually very simple to change the current limit.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert as I recently asked a similar question about a circuit I'm designing for an NiMH battery charger, but from the feedback I got, it would seem that a circuit with a current that low wouldn't need much protection. You can see the responses I got at [Solar Cell - Preventing overcharge of an NiMH battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169777/solar-cell-preventing-overcharge-of-an-nimh-battery/169802#169802).